# Prevent wrapping of subtable captions in lyx

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

[image]

Could someone provide me with an elegant solution to prevent wrapping of a table caption in lyx?  It must wrap at the end of the line, not at the end of the table.

```
%% LyX 1.6.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{table}
\caption{Valleys in promoters of genes correlated with overexpression by breast
cancer subtype}


\label{tab:vlyTallyUniqVlyMtchCntrlOvrExp}

\subtable[Number of valleys in the promoter region marking overexpresses
genes in breast cancer by subtype]{

\label{tab:vlyTallyUniqCombinedVlyMtchCntrlOvrExp}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Over-expression}\tabularnewline
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & Basal & Luminal \tabularnewline
\hline 
Marked & Basal  & 131  & 116\tabularnewline
\cline{2-4} 
Cell line & Luminal  & 100  & 104\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

}
\end{table}


%
\begin{table}
\subtable[Directly overlapping valleys in promoters of genes correlated
with overexpression by breast cancer subtype]{

\label{tab:vlyTallyUniqOverlappingVlyMtchCntrlOvrExp}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Over-expression}\tabularnewline
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & Basal & Luminal \tabularnewline
\hline 
Marked & Basal  & 26 & 18\tabularnewline
\cline{2-4} 
Cell line & Luminal  & 20 & 10\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Huh, your example does not compile for me, it complains about the `\subtable` command.

Comment: Ah... your included file is a bit odd. It probably should `\usepackage{subfigure}`, and I am not quite sure why lyx decided that your two subtables ought to belong to two separate `table` environments.

Comment: I don't think either `subfigure` or `subfig` will do what you want. After all, one of the goals of those packages allow the subfloats to fit on the same line (horizontally) whenever possible. So it doesn't make much sense to have an option to force the caption to be at full width.

Comment: Hi @Willie Wong.  Thanks, for the comments.  I am also not sure why lyx decided that your two subtables ought to belong to two separate table environments, I didn't create them that way before the export to LaTeX.  I believe you are right when you say my example should use `\usepackage{subfigure}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the packages `subfig` and `caption`

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top,width=\textwidth}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{table}
\caption{Valleys in promoters of genes correlated with overexpression by breast
cancer subtype}\label{tab:vlyTallyUniqVlyMtchCntrlOvrExp}
\centering
\subfloat[Number of valleys in the promoter region marking overexpresses
genes in breast cancer by subtype]{\label{tab:vlyTallyUniqCombinedVlyMtchCntrlOvrExp}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Over-expression}\tabularnewline
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & Basal & Luminal \tabularnewline
\hline 
Marked & Basal  & 131  & 116\tabularnewline
\cline{2-4} 
Cell line & Luminal  & 100  & 104\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\subfloat[Directly overlapping valleys in promoters of genes correlated
with overexpression by breast cancer subtype]{\label{tab:vlyTallyUniqOverlappingVlyMtchCntrlOvrExp}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Over-expression}\tabularnewline
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & Basal & Luminal \tabularnewline
\hline 
Marked & Basal  & 26 & 18\tabularnewline
\cline{2-4} 
Cell line & Luminal  & 20 & 10\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea, did not thought about that. The only caveat I see is that this solution produces overfull hboxes.

Comment: Ah, good idea there. But like Axel said, setting `\width` violates the margins. Not only does it produce hbox errors, if you started with two tables that *could* be placed side-by-side on one row, this will break subfloat. (Try removing the first column from one of the tables. The output will be clobbered.)

Comment: @Axel: true, but you already know, that not every overfull hbox will be seen in the output ... ;-)

Comment: This works in Lyx with slight modifications.

Comment: The essence of this solution as far as I can tell is to add the line `\captionsetup[table]{position=top,width=\textwidth}` before your table float.  Simple and effective.

Comment: but you have to change it when you want the subfloats side by side.

Answer (score 3):

Using the/my subcaption package instead of subfig one can use the optional parameter of \subcaptionbox to enlarge the width of the sub-figure so the whole page width will be used. Example code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{table}
\caption{Valleys in promoters of genes correlated with overexpression by breast
cancer subtype}

\label{tab:vlyTallyUniqVlyMtchCntrlOvrExp}

\subcaptionbox{%
Number of valleys in the promoter region marking overexpresses genes in breast cancer by subtype
\label{tab:vlyTallyUniqCombinedVlyMtchCntrlOvrExp}}
[\linewidth]
{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Over-expression}\tabularnewline
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & Basal & Luminal \tabularnewline
\hline 
Marked & Basal  & 131  & 116\tabularnewline
\cline{2-4} 
Cell line & Luminal  & 100  & 104\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

}
\end{table}


%
\begin{table}
\subcaptionbox{%
Directly overlapping valleys in promoters of genes correlated
with overexpression by breast cancer subtype
\label{tab:vlyTallyUniqOverlappingVlyMtchCntrlOvrExp}}
[\linewidth]
{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Over-expression}\tabularnewline
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & Basal & Luminal \tabularnewline
\hline 
Marked & Basal  & 26 & 18\tabularnewline
\cline{2-4} 
Cell line & Luminal  & 20 & 10\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(Unfortunately I have no clue about Lyx, so I don't know how to port this into Lyx.)

For even more fancy stuff with subfigures take a look at the floatrow package.

Comment: This did not work for me in Lyx or Kile.  In Kile the most notable problem was that the subfigure lettering was not correct.  I'm not sure if this could be easily fixed but the other solution works for me.